# Vagrant Provisioning with Chef to Emulate Live Server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vagrant, provisioning

I have done a lot of searching through Google (and a lot has lead me here), but I'm still extremely unclear as to HOW to do this:

- Provision Apache 2.2.22
- Provision MySQL 5.1.66
- Provision PHP 5.3.27

Now, I already have my "box" setup with the proper OS that my host uses. However, with these in my provisioning of the VM on each `vagrant up`, I will have replicated the complete production environment of my live server.

I'm new to Vagrant and the entire workflow theory of utilizing VMs over my past workflow evolving MAMP/WAMP. So, any additions to what I provision each time that you feel would help me like directory permissions and other "necessary" options, would be helpful. I'm currently trying to teach myself Vagrant and Chef (decided on Chef over Puppet based on conversations I had with others) and honestly, it's not the hardest thing in the world but it's challenging when also trying to grasp the workflow as a whole.

I work alone so I'm utilizing Dropbox (Cloud Storage), Github (Version Control) and Vagrant/VirtualBox for the management of the environments.

Thank you and any help would be amazing! I'll keep looking everywhere I can but I felt making a post was necessary so I could try to key in on WHAT I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is you searching  ...

http://brandonparsons.me/2012/ultimate-dev-prod-parity-ubuntu-server-with-chef-and-vagrant/